# SQL Server 2005 Backup for small database

Tags: sql-server

I have a sQL 2005 database that currently is not being backed up at all. I need to implement a backup strategy but I am not sure how to do so. About 1% of the database is updated each day and so I would need to have my back strategy run at least every 30 minutes.

Comment: This is a question for the DBA site (I've voted to move it) but you will get a better response if you explain what research you've already done, what you've tried and what specific problems you have. There is a huge amount of information available about this topic, both in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048(v=sql.90).aspx) and elsewhere, so it's unclear what your difficulty is.

Comment: `About 1% of the database is updated each day and so I would need to have my back strategy run at least every 30 minutes.` - I don't even understand how you derived either of those numbers.

Comment: If you are running critical database Production system without any backups then you are in serious trouble. But I think final backup solution will be based on SLA (if you have any) or say how much data you can afford to lose. But I agree with @Pondlife that you need to explain your research and requirements better.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  [sqlbackupandftp](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) it is free for up to 2 databases a day. will enable easy backups to mail ftp and dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give a suggestion based on your description but I'd recommend reviewing this backup overview (especially if you're in charge of coming up with the backup strategy for a production database):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477(v=sql.90).aspx

How you arrived at 1% updated per day, I'm not sure.. but if this is really the case then I'd give special attention to the differential backup options.